# Symfony: Field Collection, returning on selected value

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

I am using a collection with type field type. This is retrieving fields from a table. I am able to add/edit the fields.

What I would like to do is only return certain fields in the collection.

eg only the fields where the column reference_id = 2

The reason I would like to do this is because I am grouping the returned values to their group.

So I will be returning multiple collections grouped by their group.

DetailsType.php

```
 $builder
        ->add('FieldText', 'collection', array(
            'type'          => new FieldTextType(),
            'prototype'     => true,
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete'  => true,
        ))
```

FieldTextType.php

```
 $builder
        ->add('label', 'text')
        ->add('value', 'text')
;
```

Edit - Added the type

DetailsType.php

```
class VillaDetailsType extends AbstractType
```

{

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('CollectionOne', 'collection', array(
            'type'          => new FieldTextType(),
            'prototype'     => true,
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete'  => true,
        ))
        ->add('CollectionTwo', 'collection', array(
            'type'          => new FieldCheckboxType(),
            'prototype'     => true,
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete'  => true,
        ))
    ;

}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'some/entity'
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the name of this type.
 *
 * @return string The name of this type
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'base';
}
```

FieldTextType.php

```
class FieldTextType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('label', 'text')
        ->add('value', 'text')

    ;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Some/Entity'
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the name of this type.
 *
 * @return string The name of this type
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'detail';
}
```

Comment: Make query and pass results: `'type' => fieldTextType($fields_with_id_2)`

Comment: @malcolm Where do I add the query Builder? I've updated my question with the type

Comment: I have created a getter in my Entity which filters what the record I need. This works great but I need to pass in variable to the getter `public function getFilteredFields($group)`. Is it possible to pass in variables in the form add `$builder->add('filteredField', 'collection', ......)`